# Creating a string array from random user input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to have a user input a random string of letters, put those in an array, then sort them alphabetically. Problem I have is putting the input into an array. What I have is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArraySort {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter letters");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = kb.nextLine();
    int stringLength = input.length();
    String[] stringArray = new String[stringLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = input;     
    }

    System.out.println(stringArray);

}
```

}

This gives me [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302 when I print.

Comment: To convert the input string to an array of characters use `input.toCharArray()`

Comment: You forgot the sorting part ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems, you're not printing the Array correctly, and you're storing the entire input in each cell of the array. Try:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = input.charAt(i)+"";  
        System.out.println(stringArray[i]);   
    }
```

Comment: Forgot about the need to iterate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are making 2 major mistakes:

1) You are assigning each string the whole input `stringArray[i] = input;`

2) You have to iterate over each element of your string array.
In `Java8` this could be done easily with [Arrays.stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

A corrected Version of your code is:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter letters");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = kb.nextLine();
        int stringLength = input.length();
        String[] stringArray = new String[stringLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
        {
            stringArray[i] = Character.toString(input.charAt(i));
        }

        Arrays.stream(stringArray).forEach(System.out::print);

    }
}
```

Btw. `String[] stringArray=input.split("");` would be much shorter.

Additional:
If you want sorted output:

```
stringArray=Arrays.stream(stringArray).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
Arrays.stream(stringArray).forEach(System.out::print);
```

And you are done.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter letters");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = kb.nextLine();
        String[] stringArray=input.split("");
        stringArray=Arrays.stream(stringArray).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);

        Arrays.stream(stringArray).forEach(System.out::print);

    }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing. How the lack of a for loop doesn't break that code I'm not quite sure yet. Also never seen that input.split(" ") thing, and the double colons.

Answer (score 0):

To get the String form of an array, use the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class `toString` method.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
```

Also note the `sort` method of this class, although in the code's current state each item of your array will be equal to the input line.

Comment: What is the difference between treating each individual letter in the array as a char and getting the String form?